# Twos complement notation question?

Tags: binary

I have a quick question how do you do the two complement system,

For example say I have in two complement a $6$ which is $0110$ and $3$ which is $0011$ and I want to add

$6+(-3)$ I know what five is in binary but how do I find $-3$ is so that I can add them. That is my question I heard I have to find the complement and add 1.

Comment: Your binary for $5$ is not correct.

Comment: yes I meant six i got confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can "invert" the digits of 3 ($0 \to 1, 1 \to 0$) and ADD 1 to obtain -3 in two's complement.  So 0011 is the base two representation of 3, and its complement (-3) is therefore 1100 + 1 = 1101.

Hence $6 + (-3) = 0110 + 1101 = 0011 = 3$ as desired.

Comment: so  you invert the digits of 0 and 1 to find the complement and then add 1 to find the negative.

Comment: Inverting the digits gives ones' complement, not the twos' complement.

Comment: You invert digits, and add 1, to get two's complement.

Comment: yes sorry I meant the complement.

Comment: It takes a little getting used to. The more bits you use, the larger the numbers you can work with.

Comment: yes that makes sense thanks

Answer (score 2):

$5$ is $00000101$ and $3$ is $00000011$. The one's complement of $3$ is $11111100$ and the two's complement is one more: $11111101$. 
Adding gives $(1)00000010$, i.e. $2$ (fortunately).

Comment: but you do not need that many bits to 5 or 3 in binary or do you?

Comment: @FernandoMartinez:  no, you don't need that many, but we are prone to think of numbers having $8, 16, 32, or 64$ bits because that is what computers do.